# How to add users as site collection administrator group through code

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am having various site collections and I want to add few users into administrator group. So that more people will have access to edit the groups. I can add users to the site collection administrators group through
Site Actions -> Site Collection Administrators (and add users)

But I want to add users into admin group through code? I didn't get much idea about it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference with being site collection administrator. While the answer by MBsurf makes a user site admin, that will give him probably to much permissions. Using the code below you can retrieve the **Owners** group of a site and then add a user to that group:

```
// get the owners group based on permission
var ownerAssignment = (from a in site.RootWeb.RoleAssignments.OfType<SPRoleAssignment>() 
where a.RoleDefinitionBindings.OfType<SPRoleDefinition>().
Contains(site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Administrator))
select a).FirstOrDefault();

// get the assignment's SharePoint group
var adminGroup = (SPGroup)ownerAssignment.Member;
// you can now add a user to this group
```

Comment: Agreed. Much of the time Site Collection admin rights are probably too much. However, Ankit requested the user be able to edit group membership.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try this and will update about my findings :) Thanks again.. :)

Answer (score 8):

Check out this [post](http://blog.krichie.com/2007/10/25/adding-more-than-two-site-collection-administrators-programmatically/).

Here is the example from the post:

```
//if the user is not a user on the site already
someSPWeb.AllUsers.Add(“domain\\user”,”user@domain.com”,”The User”,null);

SPUser spUser = someSPWeb.AllUsers["domain\\user"];

spUser.IsSiteAdmin = true;

spUser.Update();
```

Comment: Good answer, but please remember that external links tend to die. Since we plan to stay in business for quite a while, it would be great if you could extend your answer with the code sample in the external link. Thank you!

Comment: You can replace the first two lines by : `SPUser spUser = someSPWeb.EnsureUser("domain\\user")`.

Answer (score 1):

The below property is more effective to retrieve the site (SPWeb) owner group:

`SPWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup`

Regards,

Vinicius